# Why SQL Query takes longer as subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I try to run an SQL query:

```
SELECT (SELECT
    SUM(fldAmount)
  FROM tblSession s
  LEFT JOIN tblTransMain m
    ON s.fldStore = m.fldStore
    AND s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID
  LEFT JOIN tblTransPayments t
    ON m.fldStore = t.fldStore
    AND m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
  WHERE s.fldStore = 3
  AND s.fldDrawer = 8003)
```

it takes a very long time (Around 30-40 sec)

if I remove the first `SELECT` - the query takes 0.05 miliseconds
I need the first select because the actual query I need to run is more complex:

```
SELECT (SELECT
    SUM(fldAmount)
  FROM tblSession s
  LEFT JOIN tblTransMain m
    ON s.fldStore = m.fldStore
    AND s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID
  LEFT JOIN tblTransPayments t
    ON m.fldStore = t.fldStore
    AND m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
  WHERE s.fldStore = 3
  AND s.fldDrawer = 8003
  AND p.fldID = t.fldPaymeansGroup)
FROM tblPaymeansGroups p
```

Comment: What is the point of wrapping the query as a subquery in the first place?  When you force a subquery then yes performance will decline.

Comment: I have a "report generator" which takes a table in the database, example: tblPaymeansGroups
and you can select some fields to add to the report.
so
the base query is
SELECT

FROM tblPaymeansGroups p
And then - for each column you can add - I add it's subquery to the report.

Comment: And if you do it in the other order, i.e. first without that extra SELECT, then with it? (Cold/hot data, cache etc.)

Comment: Same problem, as subquery it takes long time, without subquery it takes 0 time

Comment: Strange. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: I use SQLServer2008R2 express 
and run the query from vb.net, but the same problem happens when I run from MS SQL Server 2008 R2 management studio

Comment: @jarlh Not sure about the first query, but the second one is doing a very complex correlated subquery in the select clause.  I'm not surprised that it is very slow.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, I didn't bother to read the actual queries, isn't wrapping up as a derived table the only difference?

Comment: @jarlh No, not the second (actual) query.  The alias `p` appears inside the subquery, i.e. it is correlated.  But, I think SQL Server's optimizer was smart enough to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You may try rewriting your query with the subquery being uncorrelated:

```
SELECT p.*, a.fldAmount
FROM tblPaymeansGroups p
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT t.fldPaymeansGroup, SUM(fldAmount) AS fldAmount
    FROM tblSession s
    LEFT JOIN tblTransMain m
        ON s.fldStore = m.fldStore AND
           s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID
    LEFT JOIN tblTransPayments t
        ON m.fldStore = t.fldStore AND
           m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
    WHERE
        s.fldStore = 3 AND
        s.fldDrawer = 8003 AND
        p.fldID = t.fldPaymeansGroup
    GROUP BY t.fldPaymeansGroup
) a
    ON p.fldID = a.fldPaymeansGroup
```

Comment: Thanks, but it takes the same time as the subquery

Comment: Maybe SQL Server was smart enough to refactor your initial query into what I have above already.  Do you have any indices setup?  This is the next step.

Comment: @ErezRave.. i suggest look into plan and explore the parts which are taking more time.

Comment: all is default.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  SELECT (SELECT SUM(fldAmount) FROM tblSession s
  LEFT JOIN tblTransMain m  ON s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID
  LEFT JOIN tblTransPayments t ON m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
  WHERE s.fldStore = 3 and m.fldStore = 3 and t.fldStore =3
  AND s.fldDrawer = 8003 AND p.fldID = t.fldPaymeansGroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

For this query:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(fldAmount)
        FROM tblSession s LEFT JOIN
             tblTransMain m
             ON s.fldStore = m.fldStore and
                s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID LEFT JOIN
             tblTransPayments t
             ON m.fldStore = t.fldStore AND
             m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
        WHERE s.fldStore = 3 AND
              s.fldDrawer = 8003 AND
              p.fldID = t.fldPaymeansGroup
       )
FROM tblPaymeansGroups p
```

First, the `LEFT JOIN`s are not needed.  Because of the filtering on `t`, its column cannot be `NULL`.  So, start by writing this as an `INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(fldAmount)
        FROM tblSession s JOIN
             tblTransMain m
             ON s.fldStore = m.fldStore and
                s.fldSessionID = m.fldSessionID JOIN
             tblTransPayments t
             ON m.fldStore = t.fldStore AND
                m.fldSequence = t.fldSequence
        WHERE s.fldStore = 3 AND
              s.fldDrawer = 8003 AND
              p.fldID = t.fldPaymeansGroup
       )
FROM tblPaymeansGroups p
```

Next, you want indexes:

- `tblTransPayments(fldPaymeansGroup, fldSequence, fldStore)`
- `tblTransMain(fldStore, fldSequence, fldSessionID)`
- `tblSession(fldStore, fldSequence, fldDrawer)`

You can also throw `fldAmount` into the index (as the last key) for the appropriate table.